# How to put multiple Calendars in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

I am very young and new in google scripting. I want multiple google Calendars in a google Spreadsheet. The Debugger says that everything is right, but on my spreadsheet I don't see any results.

That is what I wrote:

```
function Calendar(){

var now=new Date();

var startpoint=new Date(now.getTime()-60*60*24*1000);

var endpoint=new Date(now.getTime()+60*60*24*100*1000);

var event1=CalendarApp.getCalendarById("df3r8epp4rpgc49eq4jmm2vot0@group.calendar.google.com").getEvents(startpoint, endpoint);
var event2=CalendarApp.getCalendarById("jie49v8l2vdhmrigruo587doss@group.calendar.google.com").getEvents(startpoint, endpoint);

var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Kalender"); 

ss.clear(); 

for (var i,o=0;i<event1.length;i++) {

ss.getRange(i,o+1,1 ).setValues((event1[i])(event2[o].getTitel()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
function addEventTitles() {

    var now = new Date();

    var startpoint = new Date(now.getTime() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000);
    var endpoint = new Date(now.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 100 * 1000);

    var cal1 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('df3r8epp4rpgc49eq4jmm2vot0@group.calendar.google.com');
    var cal2 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('jie49v8l2vdhmrigruo587doss@group.calendar.google.com');

    var events1 = cal1.getEvents(startpoint, endpoint);
    var events2 = cal2.getEvents(startpoint, endpoint);

    var allEvents = events1.concat(events2);
    // Put all the events into one array so we can loop through them

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Kalender');

    sheet.clear();

    var eventTitles = [];
    // Create an empty array we can add the titles to

    for (var i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++) {
        eventTitles.push([allEvents[i].getTitle()]);
        // Add each event title to the eventTitles array as an array (that's why it's surrounded by square brackets)
        // Titles are added as an array due to Google's 2d array useage for row and column representation
    }

    sheet.getRange(1, 1, eventTitles.length, 1).setValues(eventTitles);
}
```

---

#### References

[Muliti-dimentional arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Multi-dimensional_arrays)

[Concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

[For loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)